# A decomposition of incompressible vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fluid-dynamics

In Andrew, Majda- Vorticity and incompressible flow page 93, there is a theorem which is not proved:

Take a smooth incompressible (free divergence) vector field $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Call $w$ its vorticity (its curl), and suppose it is $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
Then $v$ admits a radial energy decomposition, which means:

There exists a radially symmetric smooth scalar field $\overline{w}$ such that we can write $v = u + b$ where $u$ and $b$ satisfy:

$u$ is divergence free and $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
$b(x)= x^{\perp}|x|^{-2}\int_0^{|x|} s\overline{w}(s)ds $.

In the page before we prove that for a smooth incompressible vector field, using the biot savart law: $v(x) = (K_2 \ast w) (x) $ and making a taylor expansion of order 1 of the kernel $K_2$: for large $x$, $v(x)= x^{\perp}|x|^{-2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w + O(|x|^{-2})$ and it is supposed to be a consequence of that, but I don't see why !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $v$ a smooth incompressible vector field and call $w$ its vorticity.

If $w\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, the number
\begin{align*}
\alpha := \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w \,dx,
\end{align*}
is well-defined. Looking at Example 2.1. on p.47 (so-called "radial eddies"), we now that for any function $\overline{w}:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the vector field $b$ that you defined is divergence free, with curl $x\mapsto \overline{w}(|x|)$, so you just have to choose $\overline{\omega}$ properly to insure that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \overline{w}(|x|)\,dx = 2\pi \int_0^\infty r \,\overline{w}(r)dr  = \alpha, 
\end{align*}
and you're done since $u:=v-b$ is then divergence-free vector field having a vorticity with $0$ mean on $\mathbb{R}^2$ : the Taylor expansion you mentionned allows to conclude that $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Just one more question, the second function of your decomposition is of the form $K_2 \ast b$ whereas in my decomposition it is of the form $bK_2$ Are the two forms equal when $b$ is radial ?

Comment: You were right, I read your question quickly and read $K_2 * b$ instead of $b K_2$, in fact it is even simpler (using the eddies), I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write complete and exact answers it has been really helpful, thanks to your previous posts and the next pages in the vertozzi book I was able to figure it out.

Comment: I would like to point out the fact that the Taylor expansion above is proved only for vorticities with compact support. If $w\in L^1(\mathbb R^2)$ has zero mean, it is not true in general that $K_2*w\in L^2(\mathbb R^2)$. Currently, I don't know how to prove the theorem. To be honest, I am not actually quite sure that the theorem is true, but I might be missing something.

Comment: I have asked a question about this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408382/radial-energy-decomposition-of-a-velocity-field-in-2d-is-anyone-able-to-show-th?noredirect=1&lq=1